# I'm entering String in a form but getting java.lang.NumberFormatException : SpringBoot hibernate Java app

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I need help with this. I've spent 2 hrs and can't find anything.

The problem: I'm entering Text in Skill and Proficiency field in an html form. The model takes String. But I get the error saying failed to convert to number.

This is the error I'm getting:

```
Failed to bind request element: 
org.springframework.beans.TypeMismatchException: Failed to convert value of 
type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'com.byAJ.persistence.models.Skills'; 
nested exception is 
org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert 
from type [java.lang.String] to type [java.lang.Long] for value 'Designing 
engines'; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input 
string: "Designingengines"
2017-07-09 15:48:57.233  WARN 16312 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] 
.w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved exception caused by 
Handler execution: org.springframework.beans.TypeMismatchException: Failed to 
convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 
'com.byAJ.persistence.models.Skills'; nested exception is 
org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert 
from type [java.lang.String] to type [java.lang.Long] for value 'Designing 
engines'; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input 
string: "Designingengines"
```

HTML Page:

```
 <form autocomplete="off" action="#" th:action="@{/skill}"
       th:object="${skill}" method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
       <!--   <label for="degree">Degree <mark><strong><span th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('firstName')}" th:errors="*{firstName}">First Name Error</span></strong></mark></label>-->
        <label for="skill">Skill<mark><strong><span th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('skill')}" th:errors="*{skill}">can't be empty</span></strong></mark></label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="skill" placeholder="Engineer" th:field="*{skill}" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="proficiency">Proficiency( Beginner, Proficient, Expert) <mark><strong><span th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('proficiency')}" th:errors="*{proficiency}"> can't be empty</span></strong></mark></label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="proficiency" placeholder="Expert" th:field="*{proficiency}" />
    </div>


    <div class="form-group">
        <p>Enter More Skills?</p>

    <input type="radio" name="yesOrNo" value="yes"> Yes
    <input type="radio" name="yesOrNo" value="no" checked> No

    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Skill Controllers:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/skill", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String getSkill(Model model)
{

    model.addAttribute("skill", new Skills());

    return "skillForm";
}

@RequestMapping(value="/skill", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String processSkil(@Valid @ModelAttribute("skill") Skills skill, BindingResult result, Model model, @RequestParam("yesOrNo") String yesNo){

    System.out.println("helo");
    System.out.println(result.toString());
    if (result.hasErrors()) {
        return "skillForm";
    } else {

        skill.setUsername(userService.getUserDetails().getUsername());
        userService.saveSkill(skill);



    }



    if( yesNo.equals("yes")){

        return "redirect:/skill";
    }

    return "myResume";
}
```

Skill Model:

```
@Entity
public class Skills {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private long id;



@NotEmpty
private String skill, proficiency;
private String username;


public String getSkill() {
    return skill;
}

public void setSkill(String skill) {
    this.skill = skill;
}

public String getProficiency() {
    return proficiency;
}

public void setProficiency(String proficiency) {
    this.proficiency = proficiency;
}

public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}

public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}

public long getId() {
    return id;
}



}
```

Finally Skill Repository CRUD:

```
import com.byAJ.persistence.models.Skills;

import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

public interface SkillRepository extends CrudRepository<Skills, Long>{

}
```

Any tip is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

UPDATE: When I try entering a number in the skill field, I don't get any error and the value gerts stored in the databse. This is really confusing, as I don't have field that's expecting integer for those values.

Comment: Looks like you are passing `string: "Designingengines"` into a field that expects `Long`

Comment: It's defined as text in HTML and String in the model so I don't know why it expects Long.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that I had the same name for Object and field and mapping. So I changed them to different names and Now the program is working.